# air conditioning working intermittently 2004 Ford Freestar

Tags: ford, ac

Hoping we can find a solution to our AC problem.  Normally our AC is just blowing out warm air when AC is on.  Warm air comes out in front and back of van.  The air does not normally work but once in awhile you can actually hear a transition happen and the air will start coming out cold.  The warm air pressure will slow and you can tell the air is switching back on.  We just had the freon tested and we have no leaks.  When we first started noticing a problem with the air it would only work if we were driving fast like on the freeway.  Once we slowed or if we were driving down a road where we had several stops it would switch and start blowing warm air again.

Hope this makes sense to someone!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an exterior temperature sensor that gives a reading inside the car?  I have a SAAB 93 that had a faulty exterior temperature sensor that the HVAC computer system used to properly run.  During the warm summer months the sensor was telling my car that is was below freezing outside and it wouldn't let the AC system come, but every now and then the sensor would show a correct reading and it would work fine.  You should check this.

Comment: yes, actually and it does not always show the correct temp.  I will definitely check this out because I haven't paid attention to the temperature as it is rarely correct.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @JROC: Good answer +1

Answer (score 1):

You said ... " When we first started noticing a problem with the air it would only work if we were driving fast like on the freeway." Is this still the case?

When you turn on the a/c does the engine's fan engage as well?  If not, the refrigerant is not properly cooling off in the condenser.

If this is the case, it is simple and free to figure out if this sensor is the culprit. The fan should engage when the a/c is in the recirculate mode.

More in depth troubleshooting instructions can be found here... 
http://www.justanswer.com/ford/27btu-2004-ford-freestar-pressure-sensor-high-pressure-half-way-tank.html

Use this as a reference if you are not sure where the switch is. [image: High side pressure switch.]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a scan on your AirCon system to check it out for any control faults and operation. A check on the blend door must be done as they do fail and continue to let in warm/hot air during AirCon operation. A system recharge may/will be necessary to ensure that it is fully charged. During the recharge pressures should be noted, and ensure that the drier and the orifice tube are servicible. The orifice tube can be blocked or resricted and could very well be the problem in line with your fault description, but a full system check would be a necessary before spending on parts.

Comment: its an odd thing.  It will sometimes blow out heat then change and suddenly blow cold.  It has been working more this week than the week before.  If the above doesn't turn out to be the case we will take it in although our weather is getting to the point that we wont need air already here in MI.  Thanks for the reply